# Render live MJPEG stream on a plane in Unity

Tags: unity, textures

I'm trying to display a live video stream as a texture in Unity. It comes from a Raspberry Pi using `motion` and encoded as MJPEG.

Is there an easy way to implement the stream in my project? I don't need controls for the stream, nor audio solution. Only the video itself.

Comment: For clarification, which part of the project are you having issues with? Applying a dynamic texture? Interfacing with the rPi? Both?